# Laravel 5.8 JWT API Login a user only if his status is active

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, jwt, laravel-controller

i am trying to implement if your trying to login in with his credentials that time login system check the account status if status ACTIVE it login else it show error notification your account has blocked.

my database column name and its value

column `account_status`

value `ACTIVE` and `BLOCKED`

**i tried this in my controller but it not working**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\UserLoginRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function login(UserLoginRequest $request)
    {

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($request->only(['mobile_number', 'password']))) {
            return response()->json([
                'errors' => [
                    'mobile_number' => ['Sorry we cant find you with those details.'],
                ],
            ], 422);
        };

        return (new UserResource($request->user()))->additional([
            'meta' => [
                'token' => $token,
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
    }

}
```

Comment: where you get $token from?

Comment: @Sok Chanty i updated my question check once

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use Auth;

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'account_status'=>'ACTIVE'])) {
   // Authentication passed...
   return (new UserResource($request->user()))->additional([
        'meta' => [
             'token' => $token,
           ],
        ]);
    }
   return response()->json([
      'errors' => ["email" => "Something wrong"]
   ]);
```

Comment: "message": "syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'",

Comment: you have to declare: $email = request('email'); before if condition.

Comment: its showing token null   },
    "meta": {
        "token": null
    }

Comment: Is it middleware or anything else?

Comment: it a controller

Comment: The token is null because you don't pass anything to $token.

Comment: wean i use my code without account_status'=>'ACTIVE  token was created , wean i am trying to use your code token not created im using JWT

Comment: i am using this doc to implement jwt https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Answer (score 0):

this code is so clean and resourcefull :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\UserNotDefinedException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;

   public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validated();
        $rememberMe = $request->input('remember_me');
        try {
            if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
                $user = Auth::user();
                if (!auth()->user()->status) {
                    throw new UserNotDefinedException('user is inactive');
                }
                $token = ($rememberMe == true) ? JWTAuth::customClaims(['exp' => now()->addDays(1000)->timestamp,])->fromUser($user) : JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
                return $this->respondWithToken($token);
            } else {
                throw new TokenInvalidException('user credential is invalid');
            }
        } catch (UserNotDefinedException $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => __('messages.login.user.deactivate')], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => __('messages.login.invalid.credentials')], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        };
    }
```